# AWS ECS cluster is not showing container

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create an ECS cluster(using cloudformation template), where i can create an instance installed with an provided AMI through Yaml file
But the problem i am facing -

In Yaml file -

I am creating a cluster then creating a service and task with minimum required values

The cluster is creating service is also creating but I can't see any Container instance there.

How can I be able to see container instance, what kind of changes/modifications I need to make in my YAML file?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share that yaml file as plain text?

Comment: vahdet text is going too large... i will share in chunks.

Comment: Resources:
  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: "TestCluster"

Comment: TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: "InShip_TestECS"
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: "TestInshipCont"
          Cpu: "50"
          Image: "any ami(for example)"
          Memory: 1024
          MemoryReservation: 384
          Essential: true
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80
          Environment:
            - Name: Tag
              Value: "v1"

Comment: ServiceDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: "TestCluster"
      LaunchType: EC2
      DesiredCount: 1
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ECS is amazon manage service you donot have any type of access to underlying resources.

ECS also known as fargate and in that task is there it & not create container instances.

there is total two launch type in ECS where

- ECS fargate launch type
- EC2 launch type

in second launch type ec2 only it create container instance and you can watch it in ec2 section while with fargate you have to manage it as task defination

Launch type definition documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_types.html

you can read more here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html

For EC2 launch type your cluster type will be same

> Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster

But SG, VPC,NATGateway and other resources will change

```
EcsHostSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Access to the ECS hosts that run containers
      VpcId: !Ref 'VPC'
```

Comment: Harsh, Thanks for the response...
i have one more query.. if we use this in our Yaml

ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: "TestCluster"

It will create a cluster with name as TestCluster which seems like instance type as FARGATE

Through Yaml can't we make Instance type of that cluster as EC2?

Comment: sure how may i help

Comment: you can make it

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task_ec2.html

Comment: @lalitbhadula https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/ECS/EC2LaunchType